# Commit only part of changes in SQL Source Control

Tags: sql-server, redgate, database-versioning

I'm currently testing RedGate's Sql Source Control (Version 3.1.3.26).

I have a table with static data which stores a SQL statement in each line.
Is there a way to only commit parts of the changes?
For example I changed 5 rows but I want to select only 3 of them for commiting.

I'm thinking of a functionality similar to one which is provided by RedGate's Data Compare, where I can decide for each row indiviually if it should be included in the deployment script.

Is this possible or do I have only the possibility to commit the complete changes of a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you must commit all of the table data changes. You may want to chime in on Red Gate's uservoice page about the [ability to filter static data](http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/39019-sql-source-control/suggestions/2102131-sql-source-control-static-views-or-table-subsets-).

Comment: I tried a lot of googling but I didn't find that one. Thanks!